# How to set the controller for a subview in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I have a view in my storyboard to which I've added a `UICollectionView`. Is it possible (using Interface Builder only) to assign to my collection view a different controller than the controller that I use for the view that contains it?

I am using XCode 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by removing the UICollectionView, and replacing it with a Container view. Then, I created a separate collection view controller, and linked it to the container view with an embed segue (ctrl-drag from the container view into the collection view controller, and choose embed).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the object to yours main view controller, like in image:

[image]

then, set in class in it settings:

[image]

and set it like delegate and data source for yours collection view.